# How do you pass a string to C#/ASP.NET using $.ajax()?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, string, parameter-passing, webmethod

This works

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Save_HH()
{
    return "abc";
}
```

This does not work

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Save_HH(string myString) // (int i, string s) (object o) etc
{
    return "abc";
}
```

This is the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/Save_HH",
    data: {}, // data: JSON.stringify({abc:123}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        btn.css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#ta_response").text(response.d);
    },
    fail: function () {
        alert("fail");
    },
});
```

This error message is POST localhost(cant post link on my new account)/Default.aspx/Save_HH 500 (Internal Server Error)

---

At this point the question seems fairly clear and concise but I was just prevented from posting it as is. I don't want to say anything more because I think it is a well formed question and saying anything else would make the reader confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace this:

```
data: {}, // data: JSON.stringify({abc:123}),
```

with this:

```
data: { myString : "test" }
```

it should work out of the box.

Just remember that the name and type of the parameter you're passing through the `$.ajax` call must match the parameter name and type you declared in the `WebMethod`. Otherwise the binding won't occur and your `myString` parameter will be `null` (in the case of a string type) inside the WebMethod `Save_HH`.

Comment: :) thank you so much. the exact answer in this case was to use data: JSON.stringify({ myString: 123 }), ...}. it looks like jQuery is doing something. but that still helped a lot. *it wont let me up vote

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax( url [, settings] )
```

`url` A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
`settings` A set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request. All settings are optional. A default can be set for any option with $.ajaxSetup().